# Fruit Ninja on Windows 8 won't update

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

I installed Fruit Ninja on Windows 8 before the official launch of Windows 8.  At the time, it was free.  The game now costs $4.99 USD, and it fails to update with Error: 0x80080057.  If I uninstall and reinstall it, will I have to purchase it?

Comment: Of course you will.  You installed it against a preview version of Windows I presume, even if you didn't, the game isn't actually free anymore.

Comment: It continues to be free for those who installed in the pre-release period. I did an uninstall and reinstall and it continued to be free

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you won't have to purchase it. If you right-click in the store, you can go to Your apps, which will show all the apps you've purchased, and you will be able to download it again.

That being said, the regular uninstall didn't work for me, I had to follow this method:

http://www.msitgeek.com/fruit-ninja-wont-update-in-windows-app-store/

Comment: This is correct. Though it updated fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Its better you do not uninstall it, because most certainly you will have to purchase it, I suggest you install fruit ninja on your chrome from chrome web store , i guess there its still free.